# Google Play Services 9.2.1 and google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

My app needs to integrate google play services and firebase;so,I have downloaded the offical demo ,complie google play services and firebase sdk, google play services and firebase sdk have been updated to v9.2.1,the demo works well on android 5.0+,but crash on android 4.4.4.

Click [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android) to download the demo!

Here is my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'

 compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is the crash log:

07-19 14:34:29.790
 25938-25938/com.google.firebase.quickstart.analytics
           E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting
                                                                                               com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg$zza:

> com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsj$zza: No acceptable module found.
>   Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg.zzbq(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5038)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4632)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4566)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:145)
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5266)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:826)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:642)
>                                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                             Caused by: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsj$zza: No acceptable
>   module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
>                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsj.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg.zzbq(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzeh(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                                                at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown
>   Source) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5038) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4632) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4566) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:145) 
>                                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5266) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:826) 
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:642) 
>                                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: please, share the link to the demo project you used or share some source code

Comment: please use this instead of play service com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1 . let me know the result

Comment: Hi V V, thx for your answer,but it's not  right to my requirement

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you should identify the specific Play Service APIs your app needs and include only those instead of `com.google.android.gms:play-services`.  Listing `play-services` as a dependency pulls in all of Play Services and causes the 64K limit on method references to be exceeded.  This creates problems when running on pre-Lollipop devices.

The complete list of Play Services APIs is [provided here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) and the Firebase APIs are [listed here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). Find the ones you need and list them in your dependencies instead of `com.google.android.gms:play-services`.

To get an understanding of all the libraries that are pulled in when you specify `play-services` as a dependency, you can look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Bob-Snyder/13b191574532ec7e04f96c641f6d0ada) or open the Android Studio tool window for Gradle and run the `androidDependencies` task under `:app\Tasks\android`.

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase is now included in the google-play-services** - see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#june_2016_-_v92 . But somehow the play-services on API 19(aka Android 4.4) do not contain usable firebase-files. So what you have do do is, compile only the used APIs from the play-services and exclude the Firebase from them.

So remove line *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'*
and replace with something like *compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-NAME_OF_USED_API:9.2.1'*

**Alternative** you could use an older Version of the google-play-services that doesn't contain Firebase.